# Most efficient way to modify a single css property on the fly from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm a CSS noob.  I have an image of an arrow that I'm using to show the user's heading on a Google map.  I want to use css transforms (e.g. `webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);`) to rotate the arrow in real time to match the user's heading (I'm pulling heading information from an iOS app; the webpage is simply embedded in the app).  What is the most efficient way in javascript to update just the `webkit-transform:rotate(ndeg)` property, considering I need to update it quite frequently to replace *n* with the number of degrees of the user's heading?

PS I already know how to inject javascript from an iOS app into a webpage; for all intents and purposes the heading information could be coming from somewhere else, I'm just interested in the javascript side of the equation.

Comment: I doubt the rate at which your data comes in will be anywhere close to the update speed for the transformation. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Blender I was more concerned with any technique that might append rather than modify css information and result in high memory consumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) said, you can use `[htmlelement].style.[styleproperty]`. Two remarks using  the textarea in this page as example (try it in the browser console ;~):

1. you can also use the regular css-property using bracket notation:

   `document.querySelector('textarea').style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(5deg)';`
2. you can reinstate the original style using

   `document.querySelector('textarea').style['-webkit-transform'] = '';`

Answer (score 2):

You can set a CSS style on an object like this:

```
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(15deg)";
```

where `img` is the DOM object for your image.  This is pretty much as simple as it gets for setting a single style on a single object.

Answer (score -3):

You can set a CSS style on an object like this:

```
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(15deg)";
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate other answers.